# Rx.js 5 : why the scan use the function returned by map

Tags: javascript, rxjs5

**Solved and Closed**

The code snippet is from [rx.js doc](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/tutorial.html#state-stores)

```
var increaseButton = document.querySelector('#increase');
var increase = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(increaseButton, 'click')
  .map(() => state => Object.assign({}, state, {count: state.count + 1}));

// We create an object with our initial state. Whenever a new state change function
// is received we call it and pass the state. The new state is returned and
// ready to be changed again on the next click
var state = increase.scan((state, changeFn) => changeFn(state), {count: 0});
```

I get confused here that why `changeFn` is the right one that returned by `map` operator?

Comment: ok. After read doc and the code again, `changeFn` actually is the `value` from observer, `state` is the accumulator. And, the observable use `map` to change `event`(which the value by default emitted by `fromEvent`) to `function`. So, that's it.